# Programmatically selecting a range in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know how to do a range like `D3:D15`. But I've started using references and addresses, so I have those start and endpoints as addresses. I don't know how to designate a range using those addresses when I need a range input into another formula, like `SUM`.

I had hoped just putting a colon ("**:**") between two addresses would do the same thing, but it doesn't.

I'm looking up the values in my real spreadsheet, but for simplicity assume any hard-coded numbers are actually the result of other calculations. For something like `E3:J7`, I want:

> address(3,5) : address(7,10)

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned “another formula”, so I’m guessing that you want to do this in a worksheet formula (rather than in a VBA function or subroutine).  Let’s start small.  Excel supports A1 (*An*)-style references and R1C1 (R*n*C*n*)-style references.  All the examples you have used (`D3`, `D15`, `E3`, `J7`, etc.) are A1-style references –– a column *letter* (or possibly a sequence of letters; columns `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are followed by `AA`, `AB`, `AC`, etc.) followed by a row number. 
R1C1-style references are almost self-explanatory –– they are built out of a row number and a column *number*, separated by the letters `R` and `C`. 
So `E3` is equivalent to `R3C5` (row 3, column 5) and `J7` is equivalent to `R7C10`.

I wish you had said a bit more about what you were already doing, so I would know what I don’t have to explain to you.  I hope you know that, in a formula, `INDIRECT("E3")` is more-or-less equivalent to `E3`, except, when you call `INDIRECT`, the string parameter can be computed.  Perhaps you don’t know that

```
INDIRECT("R3C5", FALSE)
```

is similarly equivalent to `E3`.

`INDIRECT` gives you only a reference to a single cell. 
To go from that to a range, we use the `OFFSET` function.  Its general format is

> `OFFSET(`*base_cell_reference*`,`*row_offset*`,`*column_offset*`,`*height (rows)*`,`*width (columns)*`)`

So, to get `E3:J7`, we do

```
OFFSET(INDIRECT("R" & 3 & "C" & 5, FALSE),  0,  0,  7-3+1,  10-5+1)
```

where all the numbers can be formulas (e.g., references to other cells). 
(Note: the `+1`’s are for the standard “fence-post problem” –– the range starting at row 3 and including row 7 is 5 rows high, not 4.)  The above expression can be used anywhere a simple range can be used; e.g., as a parameter to `SUM`.

---

Yet another approach to solving your problem may be using named cells. If you give cell `E3` the name `Fred`, and give cell `J7` the name `Barney`, then you can say `SUM(Fred:Barney)`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the *cells* command. You can specify row and column with numeric values.

```
Sub test()
' select range E3 to J3
Range(Cells(3, 5), Cells(3, 10)).Select

End Sub
```